# Flutter Microsoft login app crash on android 11

Tags: flutter, oauth, azure-active-directory, android-11

I'm currently using Microsoft and Google as login providers for my flutter app. After few months I build release apk and installed it on android 11 phone. When I try to login using Google it works fine. But When I try to login using Microsoft it shows email entering UI and when I try to enter email app crashes.
THis problem occurs in release mode. debug model it working fine.

IS there any solution to fix this problem?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have any crash log from the native side(logcat)?

Comment: @CbL In debug mode it's working fine. It happen only when build release apk and installing.

Comment: yea, i understand. since it is fatal, i think it is possible to capture the crash log on native side.